# How can I get multiple keys of an object that are inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, foreach

I've been trying to find something similar to what I need to do but I haven't been able to find it quite yet.

I have an array of objects like so **:**

```
const places = [
  {
    City: 'Tribuckan',
    Lat: 48569.52,
    Long: 48.5
  },
  {
    City: 'Mecca',
    Lat: 48569.52,
    Long: 48.5
  },
    {
    City: 'Dazenda',
    Lat: 48569.52,
    Long: 48.5
  },
    {
    City: 'Uzumakin',
    Lat: 48569.52,
    Long: 48.5
  },
];
```

I want to take the Lat and Long from each object and return them so they can be used in a separate function that will figure out the distance from the original object to separate coordinates a client enters.

My theory is that I need to separate each object from the array and send it to a function that will store the coordinates and compare them to the clients coordinates.

This is what I tried but its not working so I am thinking I am way off base.

```js
const places = [
  {
    City: 'Tribuckan',
    Lat: 48569.52,
    Long: 48.5
  },
  {
    City: 'Mecca',
    Lat: 48569.52,
    Long: 48.5
  },
    {
    City: 'Dazenda',
    Lat: 48569.52,
    Long: 48.5
  },
    {
    City: 'Uzumakin',
    Lat: 48569.52,
    Long: 48.5
  },
];

const firstFun = (places) => {
places.forEach(obj => funTest(obj));
}

const funTest = (obj) => {
  let Lat = obj.Lat;
  let Lon = obj.Long;
 
  compare(lat, lon);
}

const compare = (lat, lon, GUESTLAT, GUESTLON) => {
  let newLat = GUESTLAT - lat;
  let newLong = GUESTLON = lon
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Array.prototype.map` function should get you the results you're looking for. Below is an example.

```js
const places = [
  {
    City: 'Tribuckan',
    Lat: 48569.52,
    Long: 48.5
  },
  {
    City: 'Mecca',
    Lat: 48569.52,
    Long: 48.5
  },
    {
    City: 'Dazenda',
    Lat: 48569.52,
    Long: 48.5
  },
    {
    City: 'Uzumakin',
    Lat: 48569.52,
    Long: 48.5
  },
];

const compareLatLong = (locationObject, guestLat, guestLong) => {
  return {
    Lat: locationObject.Lat - guestLat,
    Long: locationObject.Long - guestLong
  }
}

const guestLatitude = 1;
const guestLongitude = 1;

const getLatLongCompared = places.map(locationObject => {
  return compareLatLong({
    Lat: locationObject.Lat,
    Long: locationObject.Long
  }, guestLatitude, guestLongitude);
});

console.log(getLatLongCompared);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You are having a guest location object with their `lat` and `long` and you want to filtered out the object as per that location from the `places` array and update the `lat` and `long`. If Yes, Here you go **:**

```js
// Input places array
const places = [
  {
    City: 'Tribuckan',
    Lat: 48569.52,
    Long: 48.5
  }, {
    City: 'Mecca',
    Lat: 48569.52,
    Long: 48.5
  }, {
    City: 'Dazenda',
    Lat: 48569.52,
    Long: 48.5
  }, {
    City: 'Uzumakin',
    Lat: 48569.52,
    Long: 48.5
  }
];

// Guest location object with different lat and long
const guestLocationObj = {
    City: 'Mecca',
  Lat: 55000.80,
  Long: 62.7
};

// Filtered out the object from places array based on the user location.
const filteredObject = places.find(({ City }) => City === guestLocationObj.City);

// Calculate the lat and long
const guestLat = guestLocationObj.Lat - filteredObject.Lat;
const guestLong = guestLocationObj.Long - filteredObject.Long;

// final output
console.log(guestLat, guestLong);
```